Intellij 2024.2 Crash
I am facing intellij idea version 2024.2 crashes on ubuntu 20.04 from some months.
Please suggest some good troubleshooting scenarios.

please add at least the error you get.  What you ask is too generic.

Hello i am not able to use intellij idea in unbuntu , whenever i start application it works for a minute and gets freezed.

I tried updating java version to 11jdk but still the problem persists.
